# Properly implement a custom grid listview control

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, controltemplate

I have an application which use three grid listview in a similar way :

[image]

(In reality, the "standard label" is a filterbox control, but for the sake of the issue I chosen the simplest visuals elements.)

I figured I can "refactor" the three list views into the same "styled" custom listview by using a `ControlTemplate` :

```
<Window x:Class="customlistview.StyledWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:customlistview"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="StyledWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style x:Key="StyledListView" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">

            <Border x:Name="_Border" Background="#ADADAD">
              <Grid x:Name="_Grid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="46*"/>
                  <RowDefinition  Height="auto" MaxHeight="25"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ScrollViewer>
                  <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ContentsItems" Grid.Row="0"></ItemsPresenter>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <Label Grid.Row="1"  Background="#FF5C8F88">Standard Label</Label>
              </Grid>
            </Border>

          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <ListView x:Name="ModulesList" Style="{StaticResource StyledListView}" ItemsSource="{Binding ModulesItems}" Grid.Row="0">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Module" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ModuleName, TargetNullValue='N/A'}"/>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>

  <ListView x:Name="ItemsAList" Style="{StaticResource StyledListView}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">
        <GridViewColumn Header="ItemsA" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemA, TargetNullValue='N/A'}"/>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>

  <ListView x:Name="ItemsBList" Style="{StaticResource StyledListView}" Grid.Row="2">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">
        <GridViewColumn Header="ItemsB" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemB, TargetNullValue='N/A'}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="SpecificToB" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SpecificToB, TargetNullValue='N/A'}"/>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>

</Grid>
```

It work, however I have lost the GridView Column Headers (and the background color has changed too) :

[image]

Whats the correct way to add a footer to a listview ?

Here the associated code :

#### StyledWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;


namespace customlistview
{
   public class ModuleItem
   {
      public ModuleItem(string Name)
      {
         ModuleName = Name;
      }

      public string ModuleName { get; set; }
   }

   public class ItemAItem
   {
      public ItemAItem(string Name)
      {
         ItemA = Name;
      }

      public string ItemA { get; set; }
   }

   public class ItemBItem
   {
      public ItemBItem(string Name, string Specific)
      {
         ItemB = Name;
         SpecificToB = Specific;
      }

      public string ItemB { get; set; }
      public string SpecificToB { get; set; }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class StyledWindow : Window
   {
      public List<ModuleItem> ModulesItems;
      public List<ItemAItem> ItemsAItems;
      public List<ItemBItem> ItemsBItems;

      public StyledWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.ModulesItems = new List<ModuleItem>();
         this.ItemsAItems = new List<ItemAItem>();
         this.ItemsBItems = new List<ItemBItem>();

         this.ModulesItems.Add(new ModuleItem("Mod1"));
         this.ModulesItems.Add(new ModuleItem("Mod2"));
         this.ModulesItems.Add(new ModuleItem("Mod3"));
         ModulesList.ItemsSource = ModulesItems;

         this.ItemsAItems.Add(new ItemAItem("ItemA1"));
         this.ItemsAItems.Add(new ItemAItem("ItemA2"));
         this.ItemsAItems.Add(new ItemAItem("ItemA3"));
         ItemsAList.ItemsSource = ItemsAItems;

         this.ItemsBItems.Add(new ItemBItem("ItemB1", "SpecificItemB1"));
         this.ItemsBItems.Add(new ItemBItem("ItemB2", "SpecificItemB2"));
         this.ItemsBItems.Add(new ItemBItem("ItemB3", "SpecificItemB3"));
         ItemsBList.ItemsSource = ItemsBItems;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you used to add a "footer" to a `ListView` IMHO is not so wrong. Your issue is that columns' headers are not displayed. The guilty is the `ScrollViewer` you are using in your `ControlTemplate`.

In the standard `ListView`'s template, the `ScrollViewer` is precisely the control which does the *trick*. Indeed to the `ListView`'s `ScrollViewer` a peculiar style is applied (a style with a definite template which shows columns' headers).

So the solution is to apply the same style to your `ScrollViewer`. We are lucky because that style uses a well defined key, i.e. the const value `GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey`. So your template will be:

```
<Border x:Name="_Border" Background="#ADADAD">
    <Grid  x:Name="_Grid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" MaxHeight="25"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ContentsItems" Grid.Row="0" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF5C8F88">Standard Label</Label>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks ! I've ended up using [this listview style](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/410217/ListView-with-Footer) but your solution is so simpler !